Removing an action route from an ASP.NET Core 8 project
I developed the following class for removing any action route in Startup.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

public static class RouteManipulator
{
    public static void RemoveRoute(Object dataSource, string routeName)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions).Assembly;
        Type type = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource");
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ControllerActionEndpointDataSource type not found.");
        }

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("_routes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var routesFieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(dataSource);
        if (routesFieldValue == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("_routes is null.");
        }

        var routes = routesFieldValue as List<object>;
        if (routes == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The type of _routes is not valid.");
        }

        var conventionalRouteEntryType = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ConventionalRouteEntry");
        if (conventionalRouteEntryType == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ConventionalRouteEntry not found.");
        }

        var route = routes.FirstOrDefault(r =>
        {
            if (r.GetType() == conventionalRouteEntryType)
            {
                var displayNameProperty = conventionalRouteEntryType.GetProperty("DisplayName");
                return displayNameProperty != null && displayNameProperty.GetValue(r) as string == routeName;
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (route != null)
        {
            routes.Remove(route);
            Console.WriteLine($"Route '{routeName}' removed.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Route '{routeName}' not found.");
        }
    }
}

where the method RemoveRoute() removes a route given by routeName from ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions object of ASP.NET Core framework.
So, I created my Startup class as following:
..
namespace Project
{
    public class Startup : StartupBase
    {
        ...

        private Object GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
            Type type = typeof(ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetOrCreateDataSource", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            var dataSource = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { endpoints }) as Object;
            return dataSource;
        }

        public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IEndpointRouteBuilder routes, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var dataSource = GetOrCreateDataSource(routes);
            RouteManipulator.RemoveRoute(dataSource, "Login");
        }

        public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }
    }
}

where:

GetOrCreateDataSource() returns the dataSource object, which is a part of ASP.NET Core framework and contains the action routes I want to remove
RouteManipulator.RemoveRoute(dataSource, "Login"); removes a route with the name "Login" from the dataSource object

When I run the code above, the following line code of RouteManipulator.RemoveRoute():
var routes = routesFieldValue as List<object>;
returns always null even if routesFieldValue has value. Maybe, I should write var routes = routesFieldValue as List<ConventionalRouteEntry>;, but ConventionalRouteEntry is an internal class (see the source code here).
Perhaps, how can I solve my issue?

Try using System.Collections.IEnumerable instead of List<object> and use foreach when traversing routes, which can avoid the type conversion failure problem. Here is the modified example: RouteManipulator.cs.
